# Getting "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required" while installing sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, scikit-learn

I am getting this error while installing sklearn module:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Even though I already had visual studio's latest version, I tried uninstalling and installing it again but still getting same error.

[Link to image of full tracback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNtaK.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Yes, indeed. Rather, use the error message to search for previous people asking similar questions. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].